# Allow pinching to zoom while animating to bearing with iOS Google Maps SDK

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using the animateToBearing method in the Google Maps SDK for iOS so that I can rotate the map with the device's compass:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/views#bearing_orientation

While continuing to call this method, the map becomes unresponsive to the regular pinch to zoom functionality. Is there any way I can get the map to continue allowing pinch to zoom while also animating to the bearing?

I'm implementing it like this:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading!) {
        mapView.animateToBearing(newHeading.magneticHeading)
}
```

Comment: Ideally it shouldn't be a problem. They both should work because the touch gestures are different. Can you show how you are implementing it?

Comment: Updated the question with implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Before you ask the location manager to update the heading, make sure that you filter it so it doesn't update at every single minuscule movement. If you do, Google Map will be animating almost all the time, and it won't respond to your gesture while animating the map.

In Objective-C this is the code:

```
self.locationManager.headingFilter = 5;
```

You may experiment yourself, but I find changing it to around 1 to 5 degrees will make it very responsive while still enabling gestures.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm sorry misinterpreted the question before. I assumed you were using animateToZoom as well.

**Answer:**
So not entirely sure if its possible because its somewhat by design. When moving the camera e.g. to a different point on the map, it logically makes sense to have a gesture stop that behaviour, and vice versa: e.g., if I'm holding the camera at a position with my held finger, triggering an explicit animation should still move it.

However, you *might* have a better time if you disable animations while changing the value, but I don't think it'll help too much because the 'set' will also stop a gesture. But an animation is more aggressively trying to stop it over its lifetime (e.g., over 250ms or whatever is the default).
Below is the implementation.

Hope that's clear and helpful.

```html
CATransaction.begin()     
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
        map.animateToBearing(value)
        CATransaction.commit()
```

Comment: Didn't seem to make any difference but thank you. I guess it's fine as designed. I'll just need to create a button to toggle it on/off easily.